# Unable to get UITextField instance from HTML

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios4, ios5

First I have created UI as shown below using **HTML and Javascript**

[image]

I am loading this on webView using **UIWebView** Class.

My Requirement : In the above image when I enter first letter in first **textBox** then cursor has to move to next textBox automatically.

Now I am getting keyboard Up when I click on each textBox, but it is not jumping to next textBox automatically.

I know that I have to use **becomeFirstResponder** and **resignFirstResponder** for this, But I am unable to get UITextField instance when I send the request from HTML when I enter each character.

Please help on this.

Comment: have u tried by using textField delegate methods..? what u have tried so far..?

Comment: I am unable to get the UITextField instance from the HTML, If I get then I can set its delegate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a UIWebView, it would make much more sense to make your Javascript code jump between the fields, instead of trying to do it from your iOS project.

You could check for a `keyDown` with either regular Javascript or jQuery if you're looking for some easier methods, and then use `focus()` to move to the next input in your HTML.

Comment: In javascript, I have tried, there also unable to achieve the required output

Comment: I have tried same way but it's not working as per the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442811/how-can-i-get-a-uiwebview-to-focus-on-a-form-input-and-bring-up-the-keyboard

Comment: I didn't mean executing the code from within iOS. why can't your HTML document contain the Javascript code? Why do you need to control it from the outside?

Comment: we have used focus() it's working fine in browsers of our system but when I load the same HTML in the webView on iOS, smart keyboard is not popping up.

Comment: Thats weird, i did the same and it works. If you want, give me your e-mail and i'll send you an example Project.

Comment: Thanks, Please send the code at my email id : prasad_rotti027@yahoo.com

Comment: Ill write something up later and send it over.