# WebView doesn't take focus automatically

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, webview

I have an embed webview in my cocoa application. However, the webview does not automatically take focus. I tried to do this with swift but it did not work:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    webView.window!.makeFirstResponder(webView)
}
```

what am I doing wrong. How can I make the webview taking the focus once the window is opened?

Comment: what on the webview are you hoping gets a first responder status? what are you looking for it to do?

Comment: If you're talking about HTML-auto keyboard, check this answer:
[How can I get a UIWebView to focus on a form input and bring up the keyboard?][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442811/how-can-i-get-a-uiwebview-to-focus-on-a-form-input-and-bring-up-the-keyboard?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: This is cocoa app. The webview holds an editable area, i.e the entire document is made editable. If I click on the view it will happy take the focus and I can start typing but it doesn't do that by default when I open the window.

Comment: did you try subclassing WebView and overriding acceptsFirstResponder to return YES

Comment: did that but did not work

Comment: @Pass I know this is really old, but I'm running into this same issue. Did you ever find a solution?