# WKWebView migration issues

Tags: wkwebview

Further to my earlier question
[Migrating iOS Hybrid App from UIWebView to WKWebview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58331247/5948260)

I have made good progress and only have a few loose ends to tidy up. The overall performance improvement over UIWebView is outstanding.

In UIWebView it was possible to set the focus on a text field programatically using

```
webView.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = NO ;
```

However this is not available in WKWebView and ever since 2016 programmers have been developing an updating work arounds (swizzles) to overcome this.

I have tried implementing the latest of these I could find on Stack Overflow, which I found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55344531/5948260

However as I am very inexperienced at coding in XCode please could someone tell me exactly how I add the above solution to my project. I have tried in vain to find examples of how exactly to do this i
on GitHub or elsewhere but to no avail.

So far I have tried copying the code provided in the above answer into a .m file and adding it to my project, but I got 20 or so errors, I then added an import statement for Foundation and most of these went away but XCode complained that it did not know what class WebViewInjection is. Also must there be a corresponding header file?. Must there be a corresponding interface statement? How does the method defined in the answer get invoked?
As I could not answer any of these, I also tried adding the method into my ViewController class. Whilst this was accepted with no errors, it had no effect on my app, ie. the keyboard did not come up automatically.

I would also want the webview to resize to appear above the keyboard and not to scroll to where the text field is as this seems a very messy solution to me.

All help very gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now managed to get the keyboard displayed by adding

```
[self allowDisplayingKeyboardWithoutUserAction];
```

to viewDidLoad

I kept the allowDisplayingKeyboardWithoutUserAction method declaration inside my ViewController but changed the + infront of the method declaration to a - and this seems to have worked.

I still do not know how to resize the webview when the keyboard is displayed.

Comment: Hi @Steve, This one is not working on 13.6 for me and iOS 14 beta. Any change in that method required?

Comment: Thanks for the warning that more research will be needed. I have only updated to 13.4 so far so I had not noticed but I have a new iPhone arriving at the weekend so I am sure I would have found out then. Why on earth can't the world stop moving? In answer to your question I do not know. Sorry.

Comment: Hi @Harsh, It still works for me on 13.6 and 13.7. Not yet tested on 14