# Why javascript code works on simulator but not on iOS devices?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, focus, wkwebview

I'm using this trick with UIWebView to focus an contentEditable div. Since UIWebView will be deprecated (one day haha), I want to use WKWebView.
I don't understand why, but with WKWebView, it works on a simulator, but not with real devices.

I put a class so you can copy/past and see the magic !

Thanks,

Pierre

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class StackOverflowViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let html = """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
         
            <style>
                #editor {overflow: none; display: block; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue'; color: black;font-size: 16px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
                #editor:focus { outline: 0px solid transparent; }
                img { width: 100%; }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
Body here
            <div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
"""
    
    var webView: WKWebView!
    var button: UIButton!
    var textfield: UITextField!
    var stackView: UIStackView!
    
    fileprivate func initializeStackView() {
        stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    fileprivate func initializeButton() {
        button = UIButton()
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.setTitle("tap on red view to focus webView", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    fileprivate func initializeTextField() {
        textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        textfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textfield.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        textfield.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(textfield)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        initializeStackView()
        initializeButton()
        initializeTextField()
        
        webView = WKWebView()
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(webView)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
        webView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func tapButton() {
        webView.becomeFirstResponder()
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('editor').focus();")
    }
}
```

I added this extension from Pranit Harekar: [Programmatically focus on a form in a webview (WKWebView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449870/programmatically-focus-on-a-form-in-a-webview-wkwebview)

I didn't needed to add TextArea, it works with a contentEditable div! you just need to call

```
        webView.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = false
```

Comment: is webview visible in device?

Comment: Looks like there's an [issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=142757) in WebKit with setting focus programmatically. Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449870/programmatically-focus-on-a-form-in-a-webview-wkwebview) for more details

Comment: Thank you ! I use Pranit Harekar extension and its work great !